# What controls the events sent to a event log Microsoft Event Viewer?

Tags: logging

We have several events in The Tridion event log and want to see if we can disable some of these from showing up in the event log.

Comment: Please add the version of Tridion you're using as a tag to this question.

Comment: Please mention events messages which you are encountered frequently, this helps us to give better information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off verbose logging from templates by following the steps in [this article](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/quick-tip-turn-off-verbose-template-logging-in-tridion-event-log)

1. On your publisher server, open /bin/TcmPublisher.exe.config
2. Find the `loggingConfiguration/specialSources/allEvents` element and change the
   switchValue from `Information` to `Warning` or `Error`
3. Save the file and restart the publisher service

Answer (score 4):

These events are recorded by the Tridion code calling the Windows logging APIs. Once that's happened, you can't prevent the log entry being created. The only way you could have filtering would be if Tridion had made the logging of certain events configurable. I am not aware of any such configuration possibilities.

Having said that, all is not lost, as Windows has good support for being able to filter the output from the logs once it's written. Have a look in the Event viewer for "Create custom view". You should be able to create a view filtered on your own choice of event log and source, category etc.